# Django Unitest: Table doesn't exist

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-unittest

I created a simple test case like this:

```
from unittest import TestCase
import user_manager


class UserTest(TestCase):
    def test_register(self):
        email = "dung7@gmail.com"
        password = "123456"
        result, user = user_manager.setup_new_user(email, password)
        self.assertEqual(result, CodeID.SUCCESS)
```

Then I run the testcase:

```
python manage.py test users
```

And here is the log:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
/Users/admin/Projects/MyApp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py:112: Warning: Table 'mysql.column_stats' doesn't exist
  return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
Creating test database for alias 'myapp_log'...
.FE
======================================================================
ERROR: test_register (users.tests.UserTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'test_myapp.user' doesn't exist")
```

So it created a test database but seem like it didn't create the tables. Here is my DATABASES setting:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': "myapp",
        'USER': "root",
        'PASSWORD': "",
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '',
    },
    'myapp_log': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': "myapp_log",
        'USER': "root",
        'PASSWORD': "",
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '',
    },
}
```

And my model:

```
class User(BaseModel):
    uid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    create_time = models.IntegerField()
    update_time = models.IntegerField()
    status = models.IntegerField()
    social_token = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    social_app = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user'
```

Anyone know why the table 'user' is not created?

UPDATE:

user_manager from my testcase will do some query and add new record on table user.

And I thought when I run the testcase, Django will somehow read my models and create a test database with all the table from those models. Am I right about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found out I need to put my models.py in my users' folder and add 'users' into the `INSTALLED_APPS` setting. Now it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your test database needs to be different than your production database. Test databases are destroyed once the test cases are run. In your case the database was not created. You should go through this documentation for detailed information https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/overview/ 
Can you also add the snippet of your user_manager module

Comment: My user_manager do some query and add new record on table User. So should I create a new database just for test, I thought django will somehow read my models, create database and destroy when finished?

Comment: In your test file you need to import the models which you want to use,  then in define a set up method where you create your model instances and later define your assertions

Comment: I found out that I need to add my models.py file in my app folder, and the tables were created. Thanks for your help @VaibhavSingh